# Multisampling using FBO

Tags: opengl

i have implemented the code for multisampling using FBO but it doesnt work.

```
    glGenTextures( text_num1, tex_image );                      
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_image[0] );       

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,texture_width,texture_height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img1[0].imagedata);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

//  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
    GLint maxSamples;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_SAMPLES_EXT, &maxSamples);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboID);



    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorBufID);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBufID);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, maxSamples, GL_RGBA,TEST_2D_3D_SRC_WIDTH ,TEST_2D_3D_SRC_HEIGHT );
    //glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0 );
     glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBufID);
    // glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1,&defaultDepthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, defaultDepthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER,maxSamples, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, TEST_2D_3D_SRC_WIDTH, TEST_2D_3D_SRC_HEIGHT);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, defaultDepthBuffer );

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboID);





     glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBufID);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufID);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_image[0], 0);

    GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_image[0] );       


        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,texture_width,texture_height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,img1[0].imagedata);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );

        glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboID );
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufID );
        glBlitFramebuffer( 0, 0, TEST_2D_3D_SRC_WIDTH, TEST_2D_3D_SRC_HEIGHT, 0, 0, TEST_2D_3D_SRC_WIDTH, TEST_2D_3D_SRC_HEIGHT, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST );
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );

        eglSwapBuffers(sEGLDisplay, sEGLSurface);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"? What exactly fails? Also, what's your OpenGL version? Platform? Texture sizes?

Comment: You are aware that you never actually draw into `fboID`, right? I mean you go to all the trouble of setting it up, but then all drawing is done into `frameBuffID`. Then you blit from the framebuffer you never drew into. It's not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman... could you please suggest the changes.

Comment: @RetoKoradi texture size is 1920*1080 . opengles ver 3.0. The texture doesnt load at all and i get a blank screen. i am on ARM platform.

Comment: Since you're trying to anti-alias what appers to be a fullscreen quad, I have to mention that's really not going to do anything with _multisampling_. Multisampling only eliminates aliasing on primitive edges (e.g. triangle "jaggies"). For texture anti-aliasing, you'd need supersampling.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently drawing into `frameBufID` instead of `fboID`.

#### To fix this problem, move this line:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboID);
```

#### Here:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBufID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufID);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_image[0], 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboID);
```

Then you will draw into `fboID` instead.

Comment: In addition, it's also missing to bind `fboID` before the `glFramebufferRenderbuffer()` calls.